# Transform vectors results into table

Tags: r, vector

I have a list of vectors EX_DVA, EX_DVASH that have this structure:

```
 str(EX_DVA)
 num [1, 1:10]
```

I would like to create a table with one row = one vector with colnames defined (A10_INDUSTRIES) and rowname would be the name of the vector.
I do this:

```
List_results = list(EX_DVA,EX_DVASH)
    for (i in List_results){
      i<-data.table(i)
      colnames(i) = A10_INDUSTRIES
      rownames(i) = i
    }
```

But I have this error:

```
Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : 
  invalid 'row.names' length
```

and the object EX_VA for example does not seem to be a table.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `i` for two things, that's where the error is coming from. Try using another name:

```
List_results = list(EX_DVA,EX_DVASH)
    for (i in List_results){
      dti<-data.table(i)
      colnames(dti) = A10_INDUSTRIES
      rownames(dti) = i
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is a `list` we can use `lapply`

```
dtlst <- lapply(list_results, function(x) setnames(data.table(x), A10_INDUSTRIES))
```